# Inconsistency using Java's volatile keyword

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I have the following program:

```java
class Resource {
    static volatile int i = 0;
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    Resource resource;
    String name;
    public MyThread(Resource resource, String name ) {
        this.resource = resource;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int count = 1;
        while(count <= 1000) {
            if ("T1".equals(name)) {
                if (count % 5 == 0) {
                    resource.i = count;
                    System.out.println(name + ", Resource's value = " + resource.i);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(name + ", Resource's value = " + resource.i);
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
}

public class TestVolatile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Resource resource =  new Resource();
        new MyThread(resource, "T1").start();
        new MyThread(resource, "T2").start();
        new MyThread(resource, "T3").start();
    }
}
```

---

Based on some condition, I am setting the value of volatile variable by one thread named T1, expecting the value to be reflected in other two threads T2 and T3. I am doing an atomic operation, but I am getting unexpected output:

```
T2, Resource's value = 20
T2, Resource's value = 20
T2, Resource's value = 20
T2, Resource's value = 20
T2, Resource's value = 20
T1, Resource's value = 20
T1, Resource's value = 25
T1, Resource's value = 30
T1, Resource's value = 35
T3, Resource's value = 20
T3, Resource's value = 40
T3, Resource's value = 40
T3, Resource's value = 40
T3, Resource's value = 40
T1, Resource's value = 40
T3, Resource's value = 40
T1, Resource's value = 45
T1, Resource's value = 50
T1, Resource's value = 55
T1, Resource's value = 60
T3, Resource's value = 45
T3, Resource's value = 65
T3, Resource's value = 65
.
.
```

My understanding is once T1 sets the values into Resource's i, following it, printing Resource's i value under T2 and T3 should have been the same value set by T1. In output line 9, T1 = 35 but in line 10, T3 = 20. How come ? I am not doing any non atomic operation.
Kindly let me know if I am missing out something. Thanks.

Comment: You did run 3 threads with `while` loop in each of them, you are changing shared state in `while` loop without any synchronization, so which result are you expecting? Any thread can change state at any point of time here, result is unpredictable.

Answer (score 2):

Even if code looks like "one-liner", behind the scene it is not

T1 does within `if (count%5 == 0)`

```
write resource.i
concatenate `name` and static text
read resource.id
concatenate previous text and value of resource.i 
call System.out.println
```

T2 and T3 do

```
concatenate `name` and static text
read resource.id
concatenate previous text and value of resource.i 
call System.out.println
```

All operations above are executed concurrently, so one of possible timelines could be

```
T2 concatenate `name` and static text
T2 read resource.id
T1 write resource.i
T1 concatenate `name` and static text
T1 read resource.id
T1 concatenate previous text and value of resource.i 
T1 call System.out.println 
T2 concatenate previous text and value of resource.i 
T2 call System.out.println
```

Comment: And how does this explain that the offset is sometimes e.g. 50, not just 5?

Comment: T1 obviously must print 5, 10, 15 etc. I assume @John did not provide us log from the beginning.

Comment: I'd just mention that a thread can stop execution, which leads to bigger offsets.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, Your problem is here:

```
System.out.println(name + ", Resource's value = " + resource.i);
```

That is not an atomic operation. It must *at least*;

- Fetch the value of `resource.i`,
- Convert the value to decimal notation,
- Construct a new `String` by copying the values of `name` and the given literal string and the decimal number previously computed,
- And then finally, it must call `System.out.println` on the new string.

It might do more than that (e.g., it might construct more than just one new object).

A lot can happen in between the moment when a calling thread fetches the value of `resource.i` and the moment when it finally enters a `synchronized` statement somewhere within the `System.out.println` call. For example, It's entirely believable that the `T1` thread could call `println` three times in between the moment when the `T3` thread fetches `resource.i` (value equals 20), and the moment when the `T3` thread finally calls `println` with the string, `"T3, Resource's value = 20"`.